# Null attribute check for Terraform 0.11 or later

Tags: terraform

Getting the error "object does not have an attribute subnet_domain_name" when trying to execute the below code

```
scaled_node_fqdn_host_names = "${
      formatlist("%s.%s",
      local.scaled_node_host_names,
      core_subnet.svc_subnet.subnet_domain_name)}"
```

here in this case the attribute `subnet_domain_name` is null and hence getting the above error, is there any type of null check that does terraform 0.11.x versions supports while accessing attributes?

Comment: Well, which version are you using?

Comment: The version being used here is 0.11.16

Comment: just corrected the mistake, the version limitation is to use 0.11.16 only

Comment: The concept of `null` does not exist in Terraform v0.11. Terraform v0.12 introduced the possibility of values being `null`.